# ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'django'

Tags: python, django, importerror

I am trying to learn django/make my first web app with the platform.

I am trying to set up my first url page, but the path import won't work (Import Error). The import code I used (which is pretty straightforward...)

```
from django import path
```

I am using a virtual environment venv, and have python v 3.10 and django 4.0.5.

Any pointers? The only info I could find on this is from 4 years ago, and the issue was a older version of django, which does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2):

It should be imported from `urls` package:

```
from django.urls import path
```